# How can I grep through tab completion possibilities?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, console, grep

When I press tab in a console I get this output

> Display all 2957 possibilities? (y or n)

Is there any way to use `grep` on these 2957 possibilities? I would like to search for all commands with the word "svn" in them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution is the bash builtin `compgen`. To grep 'svn' from all available commands and command aliases accessible through `$PATH`, type.

```
compgen -ac | grep svn
```

Want to search from a certain prefix (eg all commands that start with `ecrypt`)? Use [regular expressions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```
compgen -ac | grep "^ecrypt"
```

Comment: excellent answer, but what if one wants to grep tab completion possibilities themselves? I mean, it's not always triggered by the command name, but also by command parameters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `compgen`.

For example:

```
compgen -ac | grep "svn"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be equivallent:

```
for x in `echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g'`; do ls $x | grep svn; done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"); do find $i -type f -perm +111; done | grep svn
```

Very similar to totaam's answer apart from this limits its scope to executables (as Bash does). But JJE's `compgen` is another mile better.

Answer (score 1):

maybe `{,.}*svn*` helps here, e.g. `ls -l /usr/bin/{,.}*svn*<tab>`.

But, have a look on the Zsh! Here: http://www.jukie.net/bart/blog/zsh-tab-completion are some great examples how it can help to reduce your tab completion results. This includes also negation, e.g. if you want all tab-completion results without the word "foobar", or all results with even digits in the first place, subdirectory tab-completion and much more. The reason why I changed to zsh was history sharing between all open terminals.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't knew compgen, and would have suggested:

```
ls -d ${PATH//:/\/*svn* } 2>/dev/null
```

for bash.

```
${VAR//pattern/replace} replaces in VAR pattern with replace. // is used to replace every pattern, not just the first, which would be just /.
```